# Problems compiling and executing this code in C++

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I'm trying to compile [this code](http://pastebin.com/QUEMy1ur) in TurboC++ 3.0. However, I got these errors:

```
DOS.H 77: Too many types in declaration
DOS.H 77: { expected
DOS.H 77: Declaration does not specify a tag or an identifier
SARSAL.CPP 72: Cannot cast from 'int' to 'time'
```

I checked the directories of the libraries and I have run the code in BorlandC++ 5.02 (unfortunately, I get the graphics error or this error: `Constructor cannot have a return type specification`, in the method `void Agente::Agente`), DevC++ and Code::Blocks without success.

The code was provided by our AI teacher and supposedly works fine. How do I get it to compile?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnDibling don't ask me..

Comment: DOS.H? Do you have a time machine or something? Set it back to 2014 so you can join us in the right century.

Comment: Turbo C++ is ancient, and appears to be unable to compile your code.  Compile it using the intended compiler.

Comment: I would post this as an answer, but it doesn't answer your question.  **Don't use Turbo C++ 3.0.**  That compiler was released in *1991*, and the language it supports is not what C++ looks like today.

Comment: Apparently the code was written in TurboC++

Comment: Even mentioning [tag:turbo-c++] may cause downvotes on your question. It's a pretty outdated compiler, that is unlikely to be used in real productive environments. There's apparently still usage in educational environments though :-/ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  Any school that uses Turbo C++ should cease to exist.

Comment: Yes, but I used other compilers (DevC++, Codeblocks) without success

Comment: @JohnDibling I totally agree, but that seems to be reality wide spread in India (and may be other countries).

Comment: Well, OK, get rid of the return type on ctor, (and yes, get a post-cretaceous compiler).

Comment: @ArCiGo: It appears that your copy of TurboC++ is too old to compile your copy of Dos.h, and that has nothing to do with any of the code you pasted.  Additionally, constructors don't have return types.  I can't figure out what that fourth error message is talking about, as line 72 has no relevant code, and there is no `time` in your code, which means the code you posted doesn't produce that error message by itself.

Answer (score 5):

I normally wouldn't answer this kind of post (and not just because of the "TurboC++" issue) but we were all newbies at some point and needed help but didn't know how to ask for it, so I'll give you a hand.

First and foremost: **DON'T USE TurboC++**. As others have said, it's ancient and will require you to learn a language that's very different than the C++ of today and will teach you many many bad habits (e.g. `#include <iostream.h>` which is wrong).

With that out of the way, let's get started, shall we?

You define a constructor (around line 70) and give it a return type of `void`. This is wrong: constructors don't have return types. The correct syntax is:

```
Agente::Agente(void)
{
  randomize();
}
```

Perhaps TurboC++ requires a return type (see?) or perhaps this was just your mistake, but either way, this is a bug because that is not C++ code.

Moving forward, you have this on line 127:

```
if((Archivo = fopen("C:\Documents and Settings\ArCiGo\Escritorio\SOFTWARE_2\DATOS.TXT","r"))!=NULL)
```

The character `\` is special in C++ (e.g. `\n` represents a newline and `\x01` is the character with value `1`.

If you want to use it, you must escape it with another `\` like this:

```
if((Archivo = fopen("C:\\Documents and Settings\\ArCiGo\\Escritorio\\SOFTWARE_2\\DATOS.TXT","r"))!=NULL)
```

There are other places where you do the same thing. Fix those and try again. I bet that you will have a lot better luck and fewer errors to worry about.

For future reference, when you are looking for help try to post a **SHORT**, self-contained program that exhibits the error that you are getting, so that others don't need to wade through hundreds of lines of code and worry about missing header files and platform-specific differences.

Comment: What other compiler can I use? ... And sorry, I forgot to post the specific part of code

Comment: gcc, clang anything but TurboC.

Comment: Depends on your platform - for Windows, Microsoft offers the "Express" edition of Visual C++ for free and you can also get gcc through [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) - both of those options are great and orders of magnitude better than TurboC++. But, really, this is the sort of question you should be asking Google.